# How to extract characters from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a column by extract characters from other column.

I have this

[image: df]

And I expected this

[image: df_new]

I wrote this

```
df['Model'] = df['AssemblyName'].str[3:8]
df.tail()
```

but I get an error when running this code:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Please add the properly formatted actual code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

use `df = df.assign(Model=df['AssemblyName'].str[3:8])` or 
`df.loc[:, 'Model'] = df['AssemblyName'].str[3:8]`
 like the message recommends to avoid these message again.

For long explanation, read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), *indexing-view-versus-copy* section for more detail.